# passing values to nest activity from diff lists

Tags: java, android

i have a problem of passing two values in different `ArrayList`s.

I made a listView and fetched to it list2 elements. when click on the listView item want to pass the selected item and the element in the list1 at the same position. The problem in next code that its pass only the selected item from listView?? how can i make it work to pass both values to next activity?

```
lv = getListView();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
setListAdapter(adapter); 

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id)
    {
         //int c=parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
           String bb=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           Intent i = new Intent(LastActivity.this, Details.class);
          String ur=links.get(position).toString();
           //  String x=edt.getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("name",bb);
            i.putExtra("link",ur);
            // starting new activity
            startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Your shown code is not helpful.

Comment: Did you check the `bb` value before adding it to the `Intent`'s extra?
How do you get the values on the new activity and what is the result?

Comment: @LukasKnuth the problem that this code dose'nt pass the values of the list 1 to the next activity

Comment: @eyal-lezmy ya I'm sure from the value of bb already it pass but the problem with ur value  from the list1 not in list2(list2 elements fetch to listView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i.putExtra("name",bb);
i.putExtra("link",ur);
```

in second activity

```
Intent i-getIntent();
i.getExtra("name");
i.getExtra("link");
```